# Wanted to install Win 7 using Virtual Box on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: virtualization

I would like to install Win 7 using virtual box on Ubuntu 14.04. I don't have Optical drive in my system so i m using bootable Pen drive of Win 7. [image]

Comment: Do you want help on installing win 7 in virtual box?

Comment: yes.
I have boot able Pen drive of Win 7.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an optical drive to install it in VirtualBox. After you configure your virtual machine (memory, disk space, etc.), when you first start it you can choose to install from an ISO image or whatever source you have available.

Comment: I have Bootable pen drive however in Virtual box booting from pen drive is not available it seems

I have edited my questions.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please refer image which i have attached. It shows Optical Drive only.

Comment: At that point press the icon to the right of the combobox (the one with the yellow folder and a green arrow. It will allow you to choose another source (a virtual drive, an iso, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

To install an Os in virtual box you need to have n ISO image file of the OS.
An ISO file looks like this:
[image]

To use the ISO you need to click on the folder icon beside the combobox.

[image]

After clicking the folder icon you need to select the ISO file of your windows 7 OS.